# Scroll a partir de certo ponto com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, rolamento, chat

Boa noite...Eu tenho uma div que é a janela de um chat com as seguintes configurações:

```
<div class="container" id="chat-rbox">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Area chatlist bg-light">
            <!--area de mensagens -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
    .Area {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        display: table;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Quando eu mando a mensagem eu gostaria que ela começasse a scrolar a partir de quando as mensagem chegassem ao final do height. Tentei montar um Jquery bem básico para tentar realizar isso, mas ele sempre vai pro final desde a primeira mensagem..Alguém teria ideia de como começar a scrollar só quando atingir os 400px?

```
  function scrollParaFim() {
                    scrollTop: $('#chat-rbox')[0].scrollHeight
                }, 500);

        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara se eu entendi nem precisa de jQuery para isso, uma técnica que vc pode fazer é usar `flex` com `column-reverse` para fazer o *scroll* começar de baixo para cima e usar `max-heigth: 400px` com `overflow-Y: auto`, assim o *container* não tem altura mínima, mas tem altura máxima, e a partir dessa altura máxima que é `400px` o *scroll* vai aparecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Area {
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.Area > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="chat-rbox">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Area chatlist bg-light">
            <div>
                <p>msg 001</p>
                <p>msg 002</p>
                <p>msg 003</p>
                <p>msg 004</p>
                <p>msg 005</p>
                <p>msg 006</p>
                <p>msg 007</p>
                <p>msg 008</p>
                <p>msg 009</p>
                <p>msg 010</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```